# How to move the n number of files which is inside the directory called directory1 to a new directory

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, xargs

I have a list of files inside directory1 and I want to move n number of files from that directory1 to directory2. When I try xargs like this it did not work.

```
ls -ltr | head -20 | mv xargs /directory2
```

Why we can't use xargs in middle? how to move n number of files to another directory in command line ?

Answer (score 2):

First, you should not use `ls` in scripts. `ls` is for humans, not for scripting. Second, the last command of your pipe tries to move a file named `xargs` to `/directory2`. Third, `xargs` appends its inputs to the command. Even if you swap `mv` and `xargs` this will lead to execute `mv /directory2 file1 file2 file3... file20`, instead of what you want: `mv file1 file2 file3... file20 /directory2`. Finally, the `-l` option of `ls` will print more than just the file name (permissions, owner, group...); you cannot use it as `mv` argument.

Your `ls` options suggest that you want to move the 20 oldest files. Try:

```bash
while read -d '' -r time file; do
  mv -- "$file" "/directory2"
done < <( stat --printf '%Y %n\0' * | sort -zn | head -zn20 )
```

`stat --printf '%Y %n\0' *` prints the last modification time as seconds since epoch, followed by the file name, of all files in the current directory. Each record is terminated by the `NUL` character, the only character that cannot be found in a file name. The `-z` option of `sort` and `head` and the `-d ''` option of `read` instruct these utilities to use `NUL` as the record separator instead of the default (newline). This way, the script should work even if some of your file names contain newlines.

If you prefer `xargs`:

```
stat --printf '%Y\t%n\0' * | sort -zn | head -zn20 | cut -zf2- |
  xargs -0I{} mv -- {} /directory2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
n=20
cd /path/to/directory1 || exit
files=(*)
mv -- "${files[@]:0:n}" /path/to/directory2
```

Also, you may consider reading this article: [Why you shouldn't parse the output of **ls**](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)